# Getting the signal strength from a Speedway Revolution RFID reader

Tags: rfid

I'm using a Speedway Revolution R220 RFID reader from Impinj with the Speedway Connect software installed thereon. I am opening a TCP socket to the reader and am getting a list of all tag IDs read. This gets processed.

I also want to get a reading of the signal strength per tag as is possible with the MultiReader application. I'm developing an independent system running on Linux, and I can't use the MultiReader application. I just need to find a way of pulling the signal strength per tag so that I can make it visible in my application.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The Speedway Connect software should be able to deliver the Peak RSSI value for tag reads. You can find the documentation on that here: https://docs.impinj.com/display/PD/Speedway+Connect+Output+Settings

If you want more low-level control of the reader, it might be better to use the Impinj Octane SDK, that provides sample code for both C# (.NET, runs also in Xamarin Mono) and Java. You can see an example here:
https://support.impinj.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201142123-How-to-read-the-RSSI-value-using-Octane-SDK

Comment: Thanks Danny.  I'll check it out!  Appreciate the response.